# Access tied files through groovy in jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I'm building a Jenkins plugin, and am handling the UI components using Groovy.  In jelly, you can use "${it.something}" to access information in the java file tied to the jelly file, as shown here:

class:

```
public String getMyString() {
    return "Hello Jenkins!";
}
```

jelly:

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout"
         xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form">

    ${it.myString}
</j:jelly>
```

from https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Basic+guide+to+Jelly+usage+in+Jenkins.

I'd like to do the same thing in groovy, but can't seem to find an example of how it's done.  Any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After even more searching and some luck, I found the correct way to do this.  If I was to use the class in my question but wanted to use groovy instead of jelly, the groovy code would look like this (this puts the string in the textbox):

```
package something.something;

import lib.JenkinsTagLib
import lib.FormTagLib

def f = namespace(lib.FormTagLib)
t=namespace(JenkinsTagLib.class)


f.entry(title:"text", field:"text") {
    f.textbox(value:instance?.text)
}
```